# Using graphics to draw rectangle at top left corner of WinForms control cuts off one pixel of top and left of rectangle

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing, gdi+

I have a WinForms project and I'm trying to draw a rectangle at (0,0), the top, left corner of the form.  For some reason it's cutting off one pixel of height and width of the rectangle.  Here's the code:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 5), new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50));
}
```

Here is the result, blown up for clarity:

[image]

I understand I could correct for this by drawing the rectangle at (1,1), but that's not how it should work based on what I've seen from controls that are placed at (0,0) and (1,1).  For instance, here's what a panel looks like at (1,1), and it clearly has a one-pixel gap:

[image]

So my question is: why does drawing a rectangle at (0,0) not behave like placing a control at (0,0)?  Why does the rectangle get cut off by one pixel on the top and left?

Comment: It's probably 3 pixels, not 4. What Reza Aghaei is proposing is the usual adjustment if you need to paint inside the bounds of a Graphics object (applies to GraphicsPath, too, since it's the Graphics object that provides the Pen). You could also translate  the Graphics by half the pen measure: `e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(pen.Width / 2, pen.Width / 2);`. Using a GraphicsPath, you can verify whether the outline falls within the bounds with `bool outlineVisible = [GraphicsPath].IsOutlineVisible(new Point(-1, -1), pen);` and correct it, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for [`Alignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pen.alignment?view=netframework-4.8) property of `Pen` is `PenAlignment.Center` which means the drawn line will be centered over the line. So what you see is expected.

You may want to set the `Alignment` to `PenAlignment.Inset`:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(
        new Pen(Color.Red, 5) { Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset },
        new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50));
}
```

You may also want to read [`Pen.Alignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.pen.alignment?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) remarks:

> `Center` is the default value for this property and specifies that the
>   width of the pen is centered on the outline of the curve or polygon. A
>   value of `Inset` for this property specifies that the width of the pen
>   is inside the outline of the curve or polygon. The other three values,
>   `Right`, `Left`, and `Outset`, will result in a pen that is centered.